# How to get selected option ID?

Tags: javascript, html

to get the selected value from HTML select:

`options[selectedIndex].value`

what if i want to get the `"id"` on the selected option?

Comment: Have you tried options[selectedIndex].id ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
options[selectedIndex].id
```

Answer (score 16):

Without making too many assumptions (i.e. *select* is a valid SELECT Element),

```
var options = select.options;
var id      = options[options.selectedIndex].id;
var value   = options[options.selectedIndex].value;
```

or,

```
var options = select.options;
var value   = (options.selectedIndex != -1) ? options[selectedIndex].value : null;
var id      = (options.selectedIndex != -1) ? options[selectedIndex].id : null;
```

Always check for *falsity* (or values that evaluate to *false*). Ex 2 sets variables to *null* (if there is nothing selected).