# get the id of the previous field in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<td>
            <select name="ad_category" id = "ad_category" onchange="select_sub_cat(this.value)" >
                <option value="#"></option>
                <option value="jobs" id="jobs">Jobs</option>
                <option value="sales" id="for_sale">For sale</option>
                <option value="services" id="services">Services</option>
                <option value="real_estate" id="real_e">Real estate/housing</option>    
            </select>
        <span id="cat_help"><a href="">Help</a></span>
        </td>
```

IN the above code , in `<a href="">` I want to pass the id or any information of the option selected , so that clicking on help will show only the help for the particular option . But my question is is it possible to get the id of the option selected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a button or some other element that doesn't suggest navigation. An inline handler might be:

```
<... onclick="alert(document.getElementById('ad_category').value);" ...>
```

More generally, once you have a reference to the select element:

```
var select = document.getElementById('ad_category');
```

you can access various properties defined by the [HTMLSelectElement interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980):

```
select.selectedIndex // index of selected option
select.options  // collection of all options
select.options[select.selectedIndex] // the selected option (if there is one)
```

and so on.

#### Edit

You might also want to implement a more generic help system based on class values. Give your form controls a class depending on the help that should be shown. Then the help button can just get the previous form control, grab its class and show it.

e.g.

```
<style type="text/css">
.helpLink {
  color: #CC00FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var showHelp = (function() {

  var help = {
    firstName: 'Enter your first name',
    lastName: 'Enter your last name'
  }

  return function (el) {

    var helpType;
    var node;

    do {
      el = el.previousSibling;
    } while (el && el.nodeType != 1)

    if (el) {
      helpType = el.className.match(/(^|\s)help-\w+/);

      if (helpType) {
        helpType = helpType[0].replace('help-','');

        // Show help
        alert(help[helpType]);
      }
    }
  }
}());
</script>

<form name="form0" action="">
  first name: <input type="text" class="help-firstName" name="firstName">
  <span class="helpLink" onclick="showHelp(this)">?</span>
  <br>
  last name: <input type="text" class="help-lastName" name="lastName">
  <span class="helpLink" onclick="showHelp(this)">?</span>
  <br>
</form>
```

The above is just a trivial demo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the selected option's id:

```
//Place in event handler
var element = document.getElementById("ad_category");
element.options[element.selectedIndex].id
```

[Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904827/how-to-get-selected-option-id).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function on the selector, to let you know when the selector changes, and capture the ID of the selected item.

Once you have that, you can use jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) on the anchor to change the href.

Comment: The OP wants to show help related to the select when the "help" element is clicked, not update the link when the select changes value.

Comment: Ah, I thought they were looking to modify the help attr to have the ID be a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is and you even have several options how to get the job done.

Since the `select` has an ID, you can get the value like this:

```
var select = document.getElementByID('ad_category'),
    value  = select.value;

alert(value);
```

But also, since the select is a sibling to the parent of the `a` element, you can also find it like this:

```
// This example is assuming quite a lot, so it's not really the best option and is
// provided merely for entertainment or trivia.
// Namely, this code requires that it is run in context of the a-element 
// (means: 'this' refers to the 'a' -element)
// and also that the markup is exactly as in the example because of traversal.
var select = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling,
    value  = select.value;

alert(value);
```