# Get the ID of an option in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select dropdown:

```html
<select onChange={(e)=> console.log(e.target.id)} id="cars" name="carlist" form="carform" >
  <option id="a" value="volvo">
    Volvo
  </option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I would like to get the ID `a` when selecting 'volvo' from the dropdown, thus getting the ID of the **option**, how can I achieve this?

The reason why I'm trying to get an id is because this dropdown can have multiply options with the same name (they would be separated by a line)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the id (apart from logging it}?

Comment: In this specific dropdown there can muiltiple items with the same name (they would be separated by a line,) so I'm trying to identify which is which

Comment: Fix your UX before you do something like this. A user shouldn't have to chose between the same options to get different results.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but even if there aren't multiple items with the same name, I would still need to get an identifier because each name has its own id that I get with props, so just getting the text itself makes it more difficult to then attach it to its original id

Comment: Even if you want to keep multiple options with the same name (which is very dubious anyway), why not just change the value="" part of the option, which is MUCH easier to get for distinction? (the user can't see the value, just like with ids)

Comment: Thanks guys I think it's not a good question I didn't provide enough context I will close it

Comment: But Ritik's answer addresses the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get selected option ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904827/how-to-get-selected-option-id)

Answer (score 6):

Use the selectedIndex to get this.

```
var getId = document.querySelector('#cars');
console.log(getId.options[getId.selectedIndex].id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the pass the reference of 'this' and get it from there.
something like the below answer

[How to get selected option ID with Javascript not JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625516/how-to-get-selected-option-id-with-javascript-not-jquery)

---